# My bootloader crashes when switching to 32 mode

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

stdio.inc

```
%ifndef __STDIO_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
%define __STDIO_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__

bits    16
 
Puts16:
        pusha
.Loop1:
        lodsb
        or  al, al
        jz  Puts16Done
        mov ah, 0eh
        int 10h
        jmp .Loop1
Puts16Done:
        popa
        ret 
 
%endif ;__STDIO_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
```

gdt.inc

```
%ifndef __GDT_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
%define __GDT_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
 
bits    16

InstallGDT:
 
    cli
    pusha
    lgdt    [toc]
    sti
    popa
    ret
 
;*******************************************
; Global Descriptor Table (GDT)
;*******************************************
 
gdt_data: 
    dd 0                ; null descriptor
    dd 0 
 
; gdt code:             ; code descriptor
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10011010b            ; access
    db 11001111b            ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high
 
; gdt data:             ; data descriptor
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10010010b            ; access
    db 11001111b            ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high
 
end_of_gdt:
toc: 
    dw end_of_gdt - gdt_data - 1    ; limit (Size of GDT)
    dd gdt_data             ; base of GDT
 
 
%endif ;__GDT_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
```

boot.asm

```
bits    16

org 0x500
 
jmp main
 
%include "stdio.inc"            ; basic i/o routines
%include "gdt.inc"          ; Gdt routines
 
LoadingMsg db "Preparing to load operating system...", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00

main:

    cli 
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0x9000  
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xFFFF
    sti 
 
    mov si, LoadingMsg
    call    Puts16

 
    call    InstallGDT

    cli
    mov eax, cr0
    or  eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax
 
    jmp 08h:Stage3

bits 32 
 
Stage3:

    mov     ax, 0x10
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     ss, ax
    mov     es, ax
    mov     esp, 90000h 

STOP:
 
    cli
    hlt


times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Nasm

```
 nasm boot.asm -f bin -o boot.bin
```

I am creating my binary with nasm. I am creating a bootable iso file with the Magic ISO. When I open it in virtual box, I get the following error. I followed the instructions at:
http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev8.html

I added the last two lines myself in the boot.asm file to complete it to 512 bytes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/obcSq.png

Comment: I don't understand the `org 0x500`, why 0x500? What if you use `org 0x7c00`? Are the red artifacts on the VM screen your editing or are they the result of `Puts16` with a wrong `org` directive? I didn't check if the GDT descriptors are correct (I don't remember the format off the top of my head) but be sure the assembler program counter matches the expected memory layout and remember that the GDT base address is *linear*. Also, you don't need that much of `pusha/popa` or a `cli/sti` guard around the segments/GDT initialization. And be careful of absolute jumps/calls since `cs` is not set.

Comment: Finally, post the VBox log, not the Guru message (VBox is not written with OS developers in mind, it won't show a full dump on triple faults).

Comment: It was fixed when I made ORG 7c00

Comment: Good! But I really would like to advise you to take a moment to understand why it worked and what was going on before. If you will continue with OS development it will get very messy without a strong understanding of the tools and the memory layout ;)

Comment: Note that your misaligned stack (at 0x9000:0xFFFF or at 0x0009FFFF) is trashing the firmware's Extended BIOS Data Area; which will probably lead to "Bad Things(tm)".